# React Material-UI pure javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I'm trying to make Material-UI work in pure javascript (no babel, modules, jsx or such things)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
   <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8" />
      <title>Bridge Bridge.React.Examples</title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">
      <script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
      <script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
      <script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/@material-ui/core/umd/material-ui.development.js"></script>
   </head>
   <body>
      <div id="main"></div>
      <script>
         ReactDOM.render(
          React.createElement(Button, {variant: 'contained', color: 'primary'}, 'Hello World'),
          document.getElementById('main')
         );
      </script>
   </body>
</html>
```

I have this error. Could you please help?

> 'Button' is not defined

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**UPDATE**
For v3 (when this answer was originally written) the window variable was `'material-ui'`. In v4 this was changed to `'MaterialUI'`. The answer has been updated accordingly.

---

Since you aren't using JSX in your example, you don't need babel. You just need to define `Button` before using it via `const {Button} = window['MaterialUI'];`.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Bridge Bridge.React.Examples</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">
    <script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
    <script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
    <script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/@material-ui/core/umd/material-ui.development.js"></script>
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="main"></div>
<script>
    const {
        Button
    } = window['MaterialUI'];

    ReactDOM.render(
        React.createElement(Button, {variant: 'contained', color: 'primary'}, 'Hello World'),
        document.getElementById('main')
    );
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: A small note: Today I tested this script with the latest development build of Material UI. The property name for Material UI on the window property has changed from material-ui to MaterialUI. After this small change, the script still works perfectly.

Answer (score 2):

Even if you import material-ui framework, you need to indicate where the Button component has to be found.

The problem is, I'm not sure it's possible without using babel.

You will find a complete exemple here in the [Material-UI doc](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/tree/master/examples/cdn)

Answer (score 1):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Bridge Bridge.React.Examples</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">
    <script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
    <script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
    <script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/@material-ui/core/umd/material-ui.development.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@latest/babel.min.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="main"></div>
<script type="text/babel">
    const {
        Button
    } = window['material-ui']

    ReactDOM.render(
        React.createElement(Button, {variant: 'contained', color: 'primary'}, 'Hello World'),
        document.getElementById('main')
    );
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Seems it works. Thank you very much. But it's with babel :-(

Comment: @user1576055 I checked before answering :) It works!
Unfortunately, babel is a must for using JSX.
Also, check this out: https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/master/examples/cdn/index.html

Comment: This code does not use JSX so babel is unnecessary.