# How to use React Component Ant Desing in a html

Tags: reactjs, babeljs, antd

I am asking for your help. My task is pretty simple. I am using React via CDN(without Node js server) and Ant Design CDN. I need to use Ant Design components in my React App. However, It simply does not work for me. I remember, I did it a couple of months ago, but right now I cannot replicate it. There is my code below. The Chrome console says that

```
Panel.js:272 Uncaught TypeError: moment__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_2___default(...) is not a function
    at Module../node_modules/_rc-time-picker@3.7.2@rc-time-picker/es/Panel.js (Panel.js:272)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:19)
    at Module../components/date-picker/wrapPicker.tsx (antd.js:9472)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:19)
    at Module../components/date-picker/index.tsx (antd.js:9344)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:19)
    at Module../components/index.tsx (index.tsx:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:19)
    at Object../index.js (index.js:25)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:19)
```

```
Cannot read property 'Button' of undefined
```

I googled that problem and apparently, the browser does not recognize require(import) command. 
I sincerely ask for your help.
Thank you!

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en-us">
  <head>

    <!-- React CNDs -->
    <script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
    <script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
    <script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-standalone/6.26.0/babel.js'></script>
    <script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/axios/0.18.0/axios.js'></script>

    <!-- Material Design CDNs-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500,700&display=swap" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" />
    <!-- <script type="module" src="https://unpkg.com/@material-ui/core@4.4.3/umd/material-ui.production.min.js"></script>  -->
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/antd/3.23.4/antd.js" integrity="sha256-x4ITqB7m84o5/YGY7vx7hmRvoWj/Yj7Zm4+Yxipq+r0=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </head>
  <body>


    <div id="root"></div>

    <script type="text/babel">
    const {Button} = window['antd']

        class App extends React.Component {

            render() {

              return (
                <Button type="primary">
                  Test
                </Button>
              );
            }
          }
    ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root')); 
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [React Material-UI pure javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54636839/react-material-ui-pure-javascript)

Comment: @RyanCogswell you are a lifesaver. It works!

Comment: I slightly changed the subject

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Follow [this](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/tree/master/examples/cdn) example project. The imports are done a bit differently.

Comment: Link-only answers aren't really ok.

Comment: How can I use the same approach but for Ant Design? I tried, but apart from Button is undefined error, I also have TypeError: moment__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_2___default(...) is not a function

Comment: I slightly changed the subject