# React importing material-ui components not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, import, material-ui

I'm new to React.  I have a local development server (node http-server) and have installed [material-ui](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui) package.

According to the material-ui docs, to add a component, I simply import it like any other module:

```
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';
```

However, when I try this, my webserver is returning a 404 and Firefox console outputs this: `Loading module from “http://localhost:8080/node_modules/@material-ui/core/Button/” was blocked because of a disallowed MIME type (“text/html”)`

The directory is accessible because I can reference the `./node_modules/@material-ui/core/Button/Button.js` file and it is returned by http-server.  But if I import that file, I get

```
SyntaxError: import not found: default.
```

I've tried importing index.js from that directory, but get same error.

How do I import the Button component (as shown in the material-ui example) correctly?

Here is my code (being served by http-server on localhost:8080)
(I am using npx babel to compile the JSX to js before serving)

test.html:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>

    <meta charset="UTF-8">

    <title>Test React</title>

    <script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
    <script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="app"></div>


    <!-- React scripts -->


    <script type="module" src="./test.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

test.js:

```
import { Mod1 } from './module1.js';
export class TestComponent extends React.Component
{
    render()
    {
        return <h1>Hello world!</h1>;
    }
}

export const TestC2 = () => 
{
    return <h2>This is a h2</h2>;
}



ReactDOM.render(<div><TestComponent /><TestC2 /><Mod1 /></div>, document.getElementById('app'));
```

module1.js

```
// module1
import Button from './node_modules/@material-ui/core/Button';
export class Mod1 extends React.Component
{
    constructor(props)
    {
        super(props);

        this.state = {};


    }

    componentWillMount(props)
    {
        console.log("willMount", props);
    }

    componentDidMount(pp, ps)
    {
        console.log("didMount", pp, ps);
    }

    render()
    {
        console.log('render', this.props, this.state);
        return <Button />;
    }
}
```

Comment: This seems more like a issues with the server/webpack build config rather than the file. Does importing work for other npm packages?

Comment: The packages might have messed up somehow, try deleting the node_module and npm cache and rerun npm install

Comment: I just installed everything fresh.  node, http-server, material-ui, react, etc.

Comment: How is it supposed to work? Does 'import' look for a specific file in the referenced directory?  Because @material-ui/core/Button is a directory, not a file.

Comment: Have you imported any other (outside of Material-UI) packages successfully? or is this your first attempt to import something?

Comment: How are you loading the React app? Are you serving it from NPM?

Comment: I will post the full project above.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [React Material-UI pure javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54636839/react-material-ui-pure-javascript)